# Export Data MongoDB to ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I want to export data from MongoDB to ElasticSearch.Mongo River plugin is an option for me to first take dump of collection and then restore which works fine for me.But I do not want to use Mongo River plugin , I am using `elaster` to export data from MongoDB to Elasticsearch.

- Elastic Search Version - 1.3.2
- Node.js version - v0.11.8-pre
- MongoDB Version - 2.4.x

When I execute : `./bin/elaster` it says:

```
{ 
  [Error: MapperParsingException[object mapping for [collection] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?]]
  message: 'MapperParsingException[object mapping for [collection] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?]'
}
```

My Elaster Configuration is:

```
module.exports = {

  mongo: {
    connection: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/times'
  },

  elastic: {
    host: {
      host: '127.0.0.1'
    },
    requestTimeout: 5000
  },

  collections: [ 
    {
      name: "walldisplay",
      index: "walldisplay",
      type: "collection",
      fields: [
        "_id",
        "wat",
        "wct",
        "u",
        "i",
        "cd"
      ],
      mappings: {
        "collection": {
          "properties": {
            "wat":{
              'type':'string',
              'index': 'not_analyzed'
            },
            "wct":{
              'type':'string',
              'index': 'not_analyzed'
            },
            "u":{
              "type" : "object",
              "dynamic" : true,
              "properties":{
                "_id":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                },
                "n":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                },
                "st":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                },
                "id":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                }
              },
              "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "i":{
              "type" : "nested",
              "include_in_parent" : true,
              "properties":{
                "_id":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                },
                "ti":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                },
                "st":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                },
                "n":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                },
                "cst":{
                  'type':'string',
                  'index': 'not_analyzed'
                }
              }
            },
            "cd":{
              'type':'long',
              'index': 'not_analyzed'
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Also please check sample document in-line

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5406a47970b17246b9a293e1"),
  "cd": 1409721465,
  "i": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("50f693d17deed44cf000007f"),
      "st": "seo-title",
      "ti": "title",
      "n": "categoryname",
      "cst": "category-seotitle",
      "r": null,
      "c": null
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("50f693d17deed44cf000007f"),
      "st": "seo-title",
      "ti": "title",
      "n": "categoryname",
      "cst": "category-seotitle",
      "r": null,
      "c": null
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("50f693d17deed44cf000007f"),
      "st": "seo-title",
      "ti": "title",
      "n": "categoryname",
      "cst": "category-seotitle",
      "r": null,
      "c": null
    }
  ],
  "u": {
    "_id": ObjectId("50ce4f79edaffd69e40ee010"),
    "n": "Richa Sen",
    "st": "richasen",
    "id": "d8mzxlp9ekn323l6jg5s8tly1"
  },
  "wat": 1,
  "wct": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined "collection"as the type and your index as "walldisplay", the type in the mapping should be "collection" rather than "walldisplay".

> The put mapping API allows to register specific mapping definition for
>   a specific type

See if the following works

```
 ..
     mappings:{
                "collection":{
                       "properties":{
                              ...
                           }
                     }
               }
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply. Yes it helped me to proceed further. Now it gives me following Error { [Error: MapperParsingException[failed to parse [wct]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "i"]; ]
  message: 'MapperParsingException[failed to parse [wct]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "i"]; ' }
As you can see in provided document WCT => integer value and "i" is an array.

Comment: Check if you already have an index with the name - "walldisplay" and type "collection" with a mapping in elasticsearch?. Delete the mapping or the type itself and try loading again.

Comment: Yes I deleted all existing mappings by curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/*/_mapping/*' and restarted Elastic Search.But still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

WCT field is mapped as number type but one your document is having wct value as string that's why you are getting such error so try to change your wct value from string to integer.